# renderScene not showing anything

Tags: javascript, react-native

In the `ListItem.js` file which is the `renderRow` from `ListView` I added a `Navigator` but it's not showing anything in the `renderScene`

```
const item = {};

export default class ListItem extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);      
    item = this.props.item;
  }

  renderScene(route, navigator){
    return(
      <Text style={{color:'#fff'}}>Test</Text> 
      <Text style={{color:'#fff'}}>{item.title}</Text> 

    )
  }

  render(){
     return(
      <Navigator
          renderScene={this.renderScene}
          navigator={this.props.navigator} />
    ); 
  }

}
```

When I put everything in the `render()` it works fine. If I `console.log()` my `item` object in the `renderScene` it logs the item, but it shows nothing.

Comment: Does it work if you bind the function reference? `renderScene={this.renderScene.bind(this)}`. It shouldn't make a difference, just a thought.

Comment: No, that doesn't work either

Comment: If you add console.logs to renderScene, is it just not getting fired or getting any of the arguments?

Comment: If I log something in the renderScene function it will log it 10 times (= amount of items in ListView). So that does work, somehow the return doesn't work

Comment: Try wrapping your Text elements in a View so you're only returning a single node. Also, your renderscene needs to be bound to the class either by returning another function like the answer @BradBumbalough showed below or calling `this.renderScene.bind(this)`

Comment: I've tried both, but no luck. Wrapping in a view didn't help either

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I experienced a similar issue with abstracting `renderScene` into its own function, almost as if the Navigator can't handle the render. All the docs demo the render being inline. What you could do is offload the render in a separate function, but still call it inline, like this.

```
render(){
 return(
  <Navigator
      renderScene={(route, navigator) => this.renderScene(route, navigator)}
      navigator={this.props.navigator} />
  ); 
}
```

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately. Could it be that the ListItem.js is a return of `<ListView renderRow={this.renderRow()}>` and that it just fails because for every item it returns a `navigator` with a `renderScene()` ?

Comment: I don't think that should make a difference. You might need an initialScene?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ES6 syntax, there is no autobinding. You can use fat arrow syntax and do something like this:

```
renderScene = (route, navigator) => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text style={{color:'#fff'}}>Test</Text> 
      <Text style={{color:'#fff'}}>{item.title}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```